# React jank performance optimization

Tags: javascript, css, performance, reactjs, browser

While profiling the react application that I work on I see few frames duration as 300ms. Timeline results show 5.5 ms spent in rendering and 0.5 ms in scripting and painting and that adds up to 6 ms. Then why is frame taking as long as 300 ms?
Image attached below:

[image: 1]

Comment: The link is dead.

Comment: Do you really "feel" a jank, at the time you show up in the timeline. Chrome's timeline can sometimes show up a "long frame" when there is just nothing to re-render. 
You can try on this page, run the timeline, scroll in the page, wait 1 second, scroll again. In the timeline you may see a "1 second long frame". But it's just the rendering loop which is paused.

Answer (score 0):

In order to measure **React performance** you should measure the time wasted by each of your components.